# TypeScript + Solid JS Abstract Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

Given an Abstract Class used as the type of a createStore, why is my method calcUtilisation  undefined? How can I achieve using a type for the data with a method within the same class for createStore?

```
abstract class Account  {
  abstract name: String;
  abstract creditUsed: number;
  abstract creditLimit: number;

  public calcUtilisation() {
    return (this.creditUsed / this.creditLimit) * 100;
  }
}

interface State {
  accounts: [Account] | []
}

const [store, setStore] = createStore<State>({
  accounts: []
});

const addAccount: Store<State> = (account: Account) => {
  setStore({...store, accounts: [
    ...store.accounts,
    account
  ]});

  return store;
}

addAccount({ name:"Barclays", creditUsed: 11600, creditLimit: 13600 });

console.log(store.accounts.calcUtilisation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `store.accounts` is an array, so it doesn't have `calcUtilisation` method.
You should access some element of this array, e.g.:

```
console.log(store.accounts[0].calcUtilisation)
```

But event after that it will be undefined, because this method is not defined here:

```
addAccount({ name:"Barclays", creditUsed: 11600, creditLimit: 13600 });
```

Object that you pass into `addAccount` doesn't have `calcUtilisation` method. You should either specify it manually right in this object, or create a concrete class constructor that extends your abstract class and create an instance here, e.g.:

```
class ConcreteAccount extends Account {
  constructor(accountObject) {
    this.name = accountObject.name;
    this.creditUsed = accountObject.creditUsed;
    this.creditLimit = accountObject.creditLimit;
  }
}

addAccount(new ConcreteAccount({ name:"Barclays", creditUsed: 11600, creditLimit: 13600 }));
```